# Match-3 gravity games solver?

Tags: pattern-matching, match, solver, tiles, gravity

[sorry for bad English] I’m playing a game similar to candy Crush. There’s only one level, but it can be can played potentially forever, increasing points. There’s only one problem:time running down. When you match 3 same things, you earn 2 seconds. If you can’t find matches in time, time will expire soon and game over.

I’m wondering if there’s a way to automate this process. I tried opening the app from the android simulator on the pc, adding “swipe” commands in every direction and controlling them with an automatic keyboard random presser. But time always expire soon  cause random moves takes time to find the match. I’m wondering if there’s a way to find the best match every time in an automatic way. Thank you